# Is parameters passed to the function parameters?

Tags: javascript

```
f2=function(fn){
    return fn
};

f1 = f2(function(a,b){
    console.log('' + a+ b)
    });

f1(3,4);
```

output is 34

Why are the parameters(3 and 4) passed to f3?

Comment: f3 means to 
    function(a, b){console.log('' + a+ b)}

Which js feature is it?

Comment: *"Which js feature is it?"* Functions are objects. (Or you may hear "functions are first class citizens", or "JS has first class functions", or other variations on that phrasing.) References to functions can be passed around. So `f2()` simply takes the anonymous function passed to it and immediately returns it. So `f1` refers to that anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

> Why are the parameters(3 and 4) passed to f3?

The function returned from `f1`

```
f2(function(a,b){
    console.log('' + a+ b)
});
```

is invoked `()` with `3`, `4` passed as parameters `f1(3,4);`, where `a` is `3`, `b` is `4`

Comment: I got it. As @nnnnnn said, `f1` refers to the anonymous function. Thanks.